# A javaUnit that checks if the default is enabled

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have an object here private boolean disabled = true;

```
public Boolean getDisabled() {
        return disabled;
    }

    public void setDisabled(Boolean disabled) {
        this.disabled= disabled;
    }
```

and I have getters and setters of it aswell.So I want a test that sets it to 'false' and then test that: On a GET, it comes back with "false" on field "disabled".basically a unit test functionality for it? any leads welcome

Comment: getters and setters don't really require unit tests, but, if you do want to test them, what is the difficulty you have with them?

Comment: Functional test to prove this functionality works? any help on this be nice

Answer (score 0):

Inside the test method, create the object, use the setter and after that assert that the field has the value you want it to have.

It's the pattern you have pretty much anywhere for testing:

1. Init objects
2. Do action you want to test
3. Check if it resulted in what you want.

```java
@Test
void test1() {
    PhoneInfo pi = new PhoneInfo();
    pi.setDisabled(false);
    assertFalse(pi.getDisabled());
    pi.setDisabled(true);
    assertTrue(pi.getDisabled());
}
```

Comment: public void testRingDisabled() {
//        PhoneInfo dto = new PhoneInfo();
//        //set some values
//        dto.setDisabled(false);
//
//        if ()
//
//        assertFalse(false);
//
//        }
//    }     what else do I have to do?